# Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 when running pyspark

Tags: python, jvm, pyspark

when I was running pyspark in python, and the traceback:

```
17/02/17 00:01:25 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker did not connect back in time
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:135)
at
```

How can I solve it?